# List cross-identification

Tags: python

I have 4 lists, each element of list is `[x, y, ID]` type is float, float, string
About 60-70 elements in each list. 
How can I find elements with same ID and get `(x1-x2)` and `(y1-y2)` ?

Maybe there is better way that my code...
`count` = 4 (4 lists)
 `tab` is lists of list

```
for i in range(0, count-1):
    print i, ' AND ', i+1
    for e in tab[i]:  # e = [x,y,ID]
        for e2 in tab[i+1]:
            if e[2] == e2[2]:
                print (e[0]-e2[0], e[1]-e2[1])
```

EMAPLE for 2 lists

```
l1 = [ [1,2,'ID123'], [3,4,'ID888'], [2,7, 'ID673'] ]
l2 = [ [3,5,'ID123'], [5,7, 'ID673'],[13,4,'ID456'] ]
tab = [l1, l2]
```

OUTPUT should be

```
0 AND 1
-2,-3
-3, 0
```

Comment: Do you want to find elements with the same ID anywhere in all of your lists?  Only between lists?  Only in consecutive lists?  Your code will only identify elements with the same ID in consecutive lists; i.e. if you have two elements with the same ID in list #1 and list #3, your code will not find them.

Comment: can you add some short input output example as i'm not quite sure what are you trying to do...

Comment: Yes its ok. Only betwen 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 lists

Comment: What would make another solution better?  Do you want it to do it faster?  With less memory?  Does yours not work for all desired cases?

Comment: Faster and not so ugly. I dont like this construction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about make a dictionary of the IDs of the 4 lists, each dictionary element will be (ID, number of the list that contains this ID). After filling up the dictionary, you'll just need to roll over the dictionary and print out those IDs that have more than one value associated.

**Edit: Add the code example**

```
l1 = [ [1,2,'ID123'], [3,4,'ID888'], [2,7, 'ID673'] ]
l2 = [ [3,5,'ID123'], [5,7, 'ID673'],[13,4,'ID456'] ]
tab = [l1, l2]
count = len(tab)
dic = {}
for i in range(0, count):
    for e in range(0, len(tab[i])):
        if not (tab[i][e][2] in dic):
            dic[tab[i][e][2]] = []    
        dic[tab[i][e][2]].append((i, e))

print dic
```

And the result dictionary will be:

```
{'ID888': [(0, 1)], 'ID673': [(0, 2), (1, 1)], 'ID123': [(0, 0), (1, 0)], 'ID456': [(1, 2)]}
```

Comment: And how do I get (dx, dy) ?

Comment: Make the value be a tuple (list, index of ID in the list).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `enumerate`to keep track of where you are.  This solution here finds the matches in the second list from the first via list comprehension.  That will go through the entire list, but if you can assume there is only one match per list you can exit the search at your first find and save time.  But I thought it was an informative way of showing the solution.

This gives the desired output for `[l1,l2]` and `[l1,l2,l1,l2]`, etc.  The break condition there just make sure we don't run into IndexErrors.

```
def checkl(tab):

    for i,sublist in enumerate(tab):
        for elm in tab[i]:
            elmid = elm[2]
            for el in [x for x in tab[i+1] if x[2] == elmid]:
                print elm[0]-el[0],elm[1]-el[1]
        if (i+2) == len(tab):
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':

    checkl([l1,l2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to implement it as a generator functions that yields (dx, dy) pairs of differences between numbers with equal IDs. To compare different implementations i've carried out a little timing. 
The first function represents your implementation using nested for loops:

```
def f(l1, l2):
"""
Nested for loops
"""
for e in l1:
    for e2 in l2:
        if e[2] == e2[2]:
            yield (e[0]-e2[0], e[1]-e2[1])
```

The second one iterates over the sorted concatenation of lists and yields the difference between adjacent pairs if their IDs are equal. This should be as fast as sorting + linear:

```
def f1(l1, l2):
"""
Iterate over the sorted concatenation
"""
l3 = sorted(l1+l2, key = lambda x: x[2]) #concatenate and then sort by ID
N = len(l3)
for i in range(N - 1):
    if l3[i][2] == l3[i+1][2]:
        yield (l3[i][0]-l3[i+1][0], l3[i][1]-l3[i+1][1]
```

I've timed it with 2 pairs of lists of different sizes:

```
>>> #small lists
... l1 = [ [1,2,'ID123'], [3,4,'ID888'], [2,7, 'ID673'] ]
>>> l2 = [ [3,5,'ID123'], [5,7, 'ID673'],[13,4,'ID456'] ]
>>>
>>> #large lists (10k items)
... l3 = [[1,2, 'ID'+str(x)] for x in range(10000)]
>>> l4 = [[1,2, 'ID'+str(x)] for x in range(7000,17000)]
>>> assert list(f(l1,l2)) == list(f1(l1,l2))
>>> assert list(f(l3,l4)) == list(f1(l3,l4))
```

So, for small lists the first function is faster

```
>>> timeit.timeit("for dx, dy in f(l1,l2): pass", setup="from __main__ import f,l1,l2", number=10000)
0.07620218006741197
>>> timeit.timeit("for dx, dy in f1(l1,l2): pass", setup="from __main__ import f1,l1,l2", number=10000)
0.2245986360430834
```

But for large lists the second one is much faster

```
>>> timeit.timeit("for dx, dy in f(l3,l4): pass", setup="from __main__ import f,l3,l4", number=1)
37.525589103028324
>>> timeit.timeit("for dx, dy in f1(l3,l4): pass", setup="from __main__ import f1,l3,l4", number=1)
0.04416877092444338
```

Based on this we can conclude that in case of small lists your implementation is just ok as it's quite straightforward and arguably not uglier than others. If you need to process large lists the second algorithm would be faster but be aware of twice memory usage. To get dx and dy for further use you can simply iterate over the generator:

```
tab = [l1, l2]
for dx, dy in f1(*tab):
    print(dx, dy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative with a little help from `itertools` and `operator`

```
import itertools as it
from operator import itemgetter
from operator import sub

id = itemgetter(2)
xy = itemgetter(0,1)

l1 = [ [1,2,'ID123'], [3,4,'ID888'], [2,7, 'ID673'] ]
l2 = [ [3,5,'ID123'], [5,7, 'ID673'],[13,4,'ID456'] ]
tab = [l1, l2]

for a,b in it.izip(tab[:-1], tab[1:]):
    a.extend(b)
    a.sort(key=id)
    for key, group in it.groupby(a, key = id):
        z = map(xy, group)
        #z = [xy(thing) for thing in group]
        if len(z) < 2:
            continue
        (x, y), (x1, y1) = z
        x -= x1
        y -= y1
        print key, ':', x, y
        #dx, dy = [sub(g, h) for g, h in zip(*z)]
        #print '\t', dx, dyprint '\t', dx, dy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary dictionary to store the list of (x, y) pairs that have the same ID across all lists in tab. Next, iterate through the dictionary. Each value is a list of (x, y) pairs. You just need to find the difference between all pairs in this list. Repeating it for all values in the dictionary would give you what you wanted.

```
l1 = [ [1,2,'ID123'], [3,4,'ID888'], [2,7, 'ID673'] ]
l2 = [ [3,5,'ID123'], [5,7, 'ID673'],[13,4,'ID456'] ]
tab = [l1, l2]

dict1 = {}
for l in tab:
    for (x, y, z) in l:
        dict1.setdefault(z, []).append((x, y))
for (k, v) in dict1.items():
    for i in range(0, len(v)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(v)):
            xdiff = v[i][0] - v[j][0]
            ydiff = v[i][1] - v[j][1]
            print '%d, %d' % (xdiff, ydiff)
```